# Error:no applicable method for 'DefaultAssay' applied to an object of class "NULL"?

Tags: shiny, data-analysis, shinyapps, rna-seq, seurat

I am new to R, so I don't know much in detail on how the following code works. I took the following code from [a research paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627320307479?via%3Dihub) (see [GitHub repository](https://github.com/brlauuu/zf_brain)):

```r
library(markdown)

shinyUI(
    navbarPage("Emergence of neuronal diversity during vertebrate brain development",
           tabPanel("Seurat",
                 sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                        helpText(paste0("Seurat v", seurat.version)),
                        selectInput(
                            "path",
                            "Select file",
                            choices=path.to.load),
                        selectInput(
                            "cluster",
                            "Select cluster(s) -- n >= 1",
                            choices=clusters,
                            multiple = T),
                        selectInput(
                            "gene",
                            "Select gene(s) -- 0 <= n <= 2",
                            choices=genes,
                            multiple = T),
                        radioButtons("overlay",
                            label = "2 gene plot:",
                            choices = list("Overlay" = 1,"Separate" = 2)
                        ),
                        selectInput(
                            "format",
                            "Downlaod format",
                            choices=device),
                        selectInput(
                            "units",
                            "Size units",
                            choices=units),
                        textInput("height", "height", "200"),
                        textInput("width", "width", "400"),
                        downloadButton(
                            "downloadMainTsne",
                            label = "Clusters tSNE"
                        ),
                        downloadButton(
                            "downloadGeneOverlay",
                            label = "Gene Expr tSNE"
                        ),
                        downloadButton(
                            "downloadViolin",
                            label = "Violin Plot"
                        ),
                        width = "3"
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                        fluidRow(
                            withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput("metaTable")),
                            withSpinner(plotOutput("umap")),
                            withSpinner(plotOutput("umap_gene")),
                            withSpinner(plotOutput("violin"))
                        )
                    )
                 )
           ),
           tabPanel("URD",
                 sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                        helpText(paste0("URD v", urd.version)),
                        selectInput(
                            "path.urd",
                            "Select file",
                            choices=path.to.load),
                        selectInput(
                            "feature.urd",
                            "Select feature(s)",
                            choices=features.urd,
                            multiple = T),
                        selectInput(
                            "format.urd",
                            "Downlaod format",
                            choices=device),
                        selectInput(
                            "units.urd",
                            "Size units",
                            choices=units),
                        textInput("height.urd", "height", "200"),
                        textInput("width.urd", "width", "400"),
                        downloadButton(
                            "downloadTree",
                            label = "Tree"
                        ),
                        width = "3"
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                        fluidRow(
                            withSpinner(plotOutput("tree"))
                        )
                    )
                 )
           ),
           tabPanel("About",
                 includeMarkdown("README.md")
           )
    )
)
```

When I run this code, shiny app gets loaded properly, but when  select a data object to be visualized it says

```r
Error:no applicable method for 'DefaultAssay' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

And the console says:

```r
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'DefaultAssay' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

I dont know how to troubleshoot this, I tried updating `seurat` and `seuratobject` packages but it didn't work.